# Confluent Operator Based on Installation : k8 Cluster is accessible from local machine

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Trying to install Confluent Platform on top of EKS cluster based on Confluent operator Based on the following reference link . Already I provisioned EKS cluster but could not access from local . What I should do to get the access K8 cluster from local . Please help me on this  . Note : We are logging based on `aws-valut`.
reference Link : https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/operator/co-quickstart.html

**Error Message :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution for this issue . Since we are authenticating through `aws-vault` secret manager , we need to give  `aws-vault exec ACCOUNTNAME-role --` before all our commands which we are executing. All have to do that for almost every command ever in AWS.

**Example :**

[image]